# Find $\lvert m\rvert$ given $\sqrt[3]{m+9}=3+\sqrt[3]{m-9}$

Tags: real-analysis, algebra-precalculus, roots, radicals, binomial-theorem

I've already found the solution, but I was wondering if there is a faster or alternative method. My solution is found below:

$$\sqrt[3]{m+9}=3+\sqrt[3]{m-9}$$
$$(m+9)^\frac{1}{3}-(m-9)^\frac{1}{3}=3$$
$$\bigl((m+9)^\frac{1}{3}-(m-9)^\frac{1}{3}\bigr)^3=27$$
$$(m+9)-3(m+9)^\frac{2}{3}(m-9)^\frac{1}{3}+3(m+9)^\frac{1}{3}(m-9)^\frac{2}{3}-(m-9)=27$$
$$-3(m+9)^\frac{2}{3}(m-9)^\frac{1}{3}+3(m+9)^\frac{1}{3}(m-9)^\frac{2}{3}=9$$
$$-(m+9)^\frac{2}{3}(m-9)^\frac{1}{3}+(m+9)^\frac{1}{3}(m-9)^\frac{2}{3}=3$$
$$-(m+9)^\frac{1}{3}(m-9)^\frac{1}{3}\bigl((m+9)^\frac{1}{3}-(m-9)^\frac{1}{3}\bigr)=3$$
$$-(m+9)(m-9)\bigl((m+9)^\frac{1}{3}-(m-9)^\frac{1}{3}\bigr)^3=27$$
$$-(m+9)(m-9)(27)=27$$
$$m^2-81=-1$$
$$m=\pm4\sqrt{5}$$
$$\lvert m\rvert=4\sqrt{5}$$

In the third line, I cubed both sides, and then in the forth line, I expanded the left side of the equation using the binomial theorem. Is there a faster or alternative way to do this type of question? If in the question there was a higher-index root (ie. instead of the cube roots there is a higher index), I don't think my method would work, because it would take too long to apply the binomial theorem. How would solve a question in this form?

Comment: Your solution is not full. You need to substitute $x=4\sqrt5$ and $x=-4\sqrt5$ in the original equation and to show that the equality is true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\sqrt[3]{m+9}=a$, $-3=b$ and $-\sqrt[3]{m-9}=c$.

Hence, we have
$$a+b+c=0.$$
But $$a^3+b^3+c^3-3abc=a^3+3a^2b+3ab^2+b^3+c^3-3a^2b-3ab^2-3abc=$$
$$=(a+b)^3+c^3-3ab(a+b+c)=(a+b+c)((a+b)^2-(a+b)c+c^2-3ab)=$$
$$=(a+b+c)(a^2+b^2+c^2-ab-ac-bc).$$
We see that $$ a^2+b^2+c^2-ab-ac-bc=\frac{1}{2}((a-b)^2+(a-c)^2+(b-c)^2),$$

which says that $a^2+b^2+c^2-ab-ac-bc=0$ for $a=b=c$ only.

In our case it gives
$$\sqrt[3]{m+9}=-3=-\sqrt[3]{m-9},$$ which is impossible.

Thus, our equation it's
$$a^3+b^3+c^3-3abc=0$$ or
$$m+9-27-(m-9)-9\sqrt[3]{m^2-81}=0$$ or
$$m^2-81=-1,$$
which gives the answer:
$$\{4\sqrt{5},-4\sqrt{5}\}$$

Comment: In the second line, I think it should be $(a+b)^3+c^3−3ab(a+b+c)$. Also, how did you go from $(a+b)^3+c^3−3ab(a+b+c)$ to $(a+b+c)((a+b)^2−(a+b)c+c^2−3ab)$ in the second line?

Comment: @MattMath I used $x^3+y^3=(x+y)(x^2-xy+y^2)$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

Let $\sqrt[3]{m+3}=a$ and $\sqrt[3]{m-3}=b$

$a-b=?$

$a^3-b^3=?$

Can you find $ab$ and $a^3+b^3=(a+b)\{(a-b)^2+ab\}$

Comment: and $a$ must be nonnegative

Answer (score 1):

Go ahead and cube:
$$m+9=27+27\sqrt[3]{m-9}+9\sqrt[3]{(m-9)^2}+m-9.$$
Denote: $\sqrt[3]{m-9}=t$ to get:
$$t^2+3t+1=0 \Rightarrow t=\frac{-3\pm \sqrt{5}}{2}$$
Now:
$$m-9=t^3$$
will produce the answers.